# Вертикальное выделение в textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать возможным вертикальное выделение в textarea ?

Comment: За что закрываем? Всё же понятно в вопросе. Откройте кто-нибудь NPP и попробуйте повыделять текст при помощи Alt+Shift+Стрелка - вопрос, как сделать такое же в textarea.

Comment: Спасибо за поддержку. Тесла когда-то сказал : "Человек может Всё !". И я ему верю.

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Оно даже в таблицах не работает.

Если только подменять textarea на что-то другое и это обрабатывать скриптом. По аналогии с гуглотаблицами, только по ячейке на каждый символ.

Кстати, была библиотека для таблиц - допишу в ответ, если найду ссылку.